# Objective-c Byte[] and Java byte[]

Tags: java, objective-c, byte

When I use `Java` to convert a special string to byte[], its result is:

```
78
-19
-71
-54
-61
-87
12
-99
```

and when I use `objective-c` to convert the same string, its result is:

```
78
237
185
202
195
169
12
157
```

Why the byte element is greater than `128` in `objective-c`? I know the reason is about `unsigned`, but how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The way to deal with this is simply to "treat" Java bytes as unsigned, when you print them out or do comparisons.  The simplest way to do this is to use `byteValue & 0xFF` to get the unsigned value of a byte as an int, but some libraries can reduce the pain -- for example, with [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`UnsignedBytes`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html), you can do `UnsignedBytes.join(" ", byteArray)` to get space-separated unsigned bytes like the `78 237 185 ...` you give as an example.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: I use objective-c to encrypt a string with DES,but it's result is not equal to use java encrypt,so i ask this question! Can you give me a resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Java byte is signed and the Objective-C byte is unsigned.  If you add 256 to a Java byte that is less than 0 you get the corresponding Obj-C byte (the Java bytes that are >= 0 are already the same as the Obj-C bytes).  It should be easy to convert.